# operating system context switching

Tags: operating-system

Which of the following information is stored in process control block to support
process context switching?
a. The date and time of switching
b. UID
c. PID
d. Terminal from where the process was initiated
e. Estimate of the last burst used by the process

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Is that an exam question or a job interview question? Either way, StackOverflow is not a place that will help you cheat on those.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) because : "_3. Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it_"